# Conditionally negating a media query in Sass

Tags: sass

I have the following mixin ([source](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-mixin-media-merging/)):

```
@mixin media($queries) {

  @if length($queries) == 0 {
    @content;
  } @else {
    $first-key: nth(map-keys($queries), 1);

    @media ($first-key: map-get($queries, $first-key)) {
      $queries: map-remove($queries, $first-key);

      @include media($queries) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to use a condition to be able to negate the media query, like so:

```
@media not screen and ($first-key: map-get($queries, $first-key)) {
```

What is the correct syntax to add it dynamically? I tried the following without success:

```
$invert: true;
$foo: if($invert, 'not screen and', null);

@media #{$foo} ($first-key: map-get($queries, $first-key)) {
```

Error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...@media #{$foo} ": expected "{", was "($first-key: ma..."
```

The iterated queries could look like this:

```
tablet: (
    respond-to: (min-width: 421px, max-width: 992px)
)
```

Which would result in the following css when used:

```
@media (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 992px) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an explanation as to why what you have doesn't work ([this issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1957) claims that interpolation is done before the media query is parsed).

It looks like you'll need to move the `and` outside of the variable and into the media query itself:

```
@mixin media($queries, $invert: false) {
  @if length($queries) == 0 {
    @content;
  } @else {
    $first-key: nth(map-keys($queries), 1);

    $foo: if($invert, 'not', '') screen;
    @media #{$foo} and ($first-key: map-get($queries, $first-key)) {
      $queries: map-remove($queries, $first-key);

      @include media($queries, $invert) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
@media not screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 50em) {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .foo {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

And yes, you need to apply the `not` each time you nest it otherwise Sass won't merge the media query (you can't merge a `not screen` with a `(min-width: 30em)` because they're exclusive from each other).

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated